# Error when deploying web application in WeblogicServer

Tags: spring, weblogic11g

I am deploying my web project to Weblogic Server. But the application state is always "prepared". I cannot start the appliction.
The log file says:

Mar 13, 2013 10:44:56 PM ICT Warning Deployer admin-PC myserver [STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' WLS Kernel 1363189496796 BEA-149004 Failures were detected while initiating start task for application 'public_html'.

<>

Mar 13, 2013 10:44:56 PM ICT Warning Deployer admin-PC myserver [STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' WLS Kernel 1363189496797 BEA-149078 Stack trace for message 149004weblogic.application.ModuleException:

```
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:393)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(StartOperation.java:85)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doPrepare(StartOperation.java:98)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:52)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerEventListeners(EventsManager.java:123)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.registerPreparePhaseListeners(EventsManager.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContextListeners(WebAppServletContext.java:1852)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.prepare(WebAppServletContext.java:1196)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.doPostContextInit(HttpServer.java:453)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:428)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:972)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:382)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(StartOperation.java:85)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doPrepare(StartOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)

Please tell me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The deployment error is very clear

> Caused By:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener

Please make sure your Spring framework related jar files in located in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like weblogic server is not able to find the Spring web API. Make sure that the spring APIs/jar files are placed under WEB-INF/lib folder.

Alternatively, you can place all your dependent jars in a separate directory on the server and set the directory path in the Weblogic startup script.

In my project, i have placed all the thirdparty dependent jars in /sns folder on the server and have set the path in the startup script.

set JAR_CLASSPATH=/sns

set CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%:%JAR_CLASSPATH%

If you are deploying on weblogic server on windows, create a directory in any drive[say E] and place all your jars and change the startup script as below.

set JAR_CLASSPATH=E:\sns

set CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%;%JAR_CLASSPATH%

Note: on windows multiple class paths are separated by ';' where as on Linux by ':'